# OR condation in symfony find Query query

Tags: mongodb, symfony

Hi I am unable to use OR condation in my following Symfony findBy query.

```
 $searchArrayTasks  = array(
           "name" =>  new \MongoRegex('/.*'.trim($_POST['keyword']).'.*/')
           );

$documents = $dm->getRepository('WorkOrganisationBundle:Tasks')->findBy($searchArrayTasks)->sort($sortArray    )->limit($limit)->skip($skip);
```

Can any one suggest please how to use OR condation in this query.Because i want to make a search basis on different parameters Like Name OR class OR Type.

Thanks Advance

Answer (score 0):

This way (certainly in your Manager) is a bad practice.

Its purpose is for really dumb request.

2 things :

-Put your code in a Repository

-And code your query in sql or dql :

```
public function common($qb, $limit)
{
    $qb->setMaxResults($limit)
        ->orderBy('task.id', 'DESC');

    return $qb;
}

public function findByNameClassOrType($keyword, $limit)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('task');
    $qb->select('task')
        ->where('task.name LIKE ?', '%'.$keyword.'%')
        ->orWhere('task.class LIKE ?', '%'.$keyword.'%')
        ->orWhere('task.type LIKE ?', '%'.$keyword.'%');
    $qb = $this->common($qb, $limit);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Use `?` symbol to be sure that Doctrine escape your strings.

EDIT (mongodb) : with Mongo use addOr($expr)

```
$q = $doctrineOdm->createQueryBuilder('Work\OrganisationBundle\Document\Tasks');
$q->addOr($q->expr()->field('task.name')->equals($keyword));
$q->addOr($q->expr()->field('task.type')->equals($keyword));
$result = $q->getQuery()->execute();
```

For more informations see https://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html

Comment: Hello Healkiss Can you please write a full query how can i use OR condition here because i want to search by name,by client,by project i am having single text box in my UI.   Thanks Lot again

Comment: Even i doing like this:

Comment: $documents = $dm->getRepository('Work\OrganisationBundle\Document\Tasks')->findBy(array('name'=>new \MongoRegex('/.*' . trim($_POST['keyword']) . '.*/i'),'OR'=>array('type'=>new \MongoRegex('/.*' . trim($_POST['keyword']) . '.*/i'))))->sort($sortArray)->limit($limit)->skip($skip);